# Finding a string in a WIFI list

Tags: processing

I want to get a specific router info out of a WIFI scan in processing.
First I scan for the WIFI and save it into a list.

```java
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
    wifiManager.startScan();

   List<ScanResult> wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
```

then I check if any of the items equals to the router name I am searching for (" dlink").

```java
for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size();i++){

if( wifiList.get(i).SSID.toString() == "dlink"){
         con[0] = "router1 found";
}
}
```

The output is just null.
I know for a fact that the router is in there. I printed out the list, checked in which position of the wifiList the router is. Compared the SSID of that router from the list to the router name, but it didn't work. I printed out the router's name char by char and it was the same.

Comment: @c3st7n Please notice the [tag:processing] tag. See also: [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost never use `==` to compare `String` values. You should use the `equals()` function instead.

From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/String.html):

> To compare the contents of two Strings, use the equals() method, as in `if (a.equals(b))`, instead of `if (a == b)`. A String is an Object, so comparing them with the == operator only compares whether both Strings are stored in the same memory location. Using the `equals()` method will ensure that the actual contents are compared. (The [troubleshooting](http://wiki.processing.org/w/Troubleshooting#Why_don.27t_these_Strings_equal.3F) reference has a longer explanation.)

See also: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Thank you so much, really i cant thank you enough, have a great day!

Comment: @jakic No problem. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work